# Redirect to https://www.example.com

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, web, https

Currently I'm using http://example.com but I want redirect all to http**s**://**www**.example.com

I read several topics here and tried quite a few solutions to this but nothing worked for me.

My last try was this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

When I'm using this code I can see this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbD2e.png)

But it gives me this message also:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the
>   server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
>   never complete.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace example with your domain and try

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you're also trying to force www. You can do both by using this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Place this rule to the top of your `.htaccess` file and make sure you clear your cache **before** you test it.